# Overriding __getattr__ and __setattr__ methods in a class with properties

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am trying to implement a class that is a contains a mixture of dictionary values and lazily evaluated properties. I'd like to syntactically be able to access items from the class via `__getitem__` and `__getattr__` and set their values in the same fashion but using properties when and setters when present.

some example code of how I envisioned implementing this:

```python
class C(object):    
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {'akey':'avalue'}
        self.att1 = '1st attribute'
        self._prop1 = None

    def __getitem__(self,key):
        try:
            self.__dict__[key]
        except KeyError:
            return self.data[key]

    def __setitem__(self,key,val):
        self.data[key] = val

    def __getattr__(self,name):
        try:
            self.__dict__[name]
        except KeyError:
            return self.data[name]

    def __setattr__(self,name,val):
        try:
            self.__dict__[name] = val
        except KeyError:
            self.data[name] = val

    @property
    def prop1(self):
        #do expensive stuff here in real class
        return self._prop1
    @prop1.setter
    def prop1(self,newval):
        #check/change value for prop1
        self._prop1 = str(newval).upper()
```

Attribute access works fine for the property but not the `__getitem__` method.

```
In [35]: c = C()
In [36]: c.prop1
Out[36]: 'Prop1 Calc Value'

In [37]: c['prop1']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\someuser\somepath\foo.py in __getitem__(self, key)
      8         try:
----> 9             self.__dict__[key]
     10         except KeyError:

KeyError: 'prop1'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\someuser\somepath\foo.py in <module>()
----> 1 c['prop1']

C:\Users\someuser\somepath\foo.py in __getitem__(self, key)
      9             self.__dict__[key]
     10         except KeyError:
---> 11             return self.data[key]
     12
     13     def __setitem__(self,key,val):

KeyError: 'prop1'
```

I assume this is because I don't fully understand how the `@property` decorator works in a class but if there's an idiomatic way to fix this problem I would love to hear it! I know it's really syntactic sugar but it would be nice to have a flexible attribute access for the class and still be able to support keys that are not valid python variable names. The pandas.DataFrame/collections.namedtuple api's are the inspiration for this.

### **Edit**

#### Working Solution:

Thansk to @Jim Fasarakis-Hilliard for pointing me in the right direction the following code works on my system (python 3.5):

```python
class C(object):    
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {'akey':'avalue'}
        self.att1 = '1st attribute'
        self._prop1 = None

    def __getitem__(self,key):
        try:
            return self.__dict__[key]
        except KeyError:
            try: 
                return getattr(type(self), key).__get__(self)
            except AttributeError:
                return self.data[key]
    __getattr__ = __getitem__

    def __setitem__(self,key,value):
        #note order is look for property 1st so that any 
        #setter methods get used insead of attribute access
        try:
            getattr(type(self), key).__set__(self,value)
        except AttributeError:
            try: 
                self.__dict__[key] = value
            except KeyError:
                self.data[key] = value

    __setattr__ = __setitem__

    @property
    def prop1(self):
        #do expensive stuff here in real class
        if not self._prop1:
            self._prop1='Prop1 Calc Value'
        return self._prop1
    @prop1.setter
    def prop1(self,newval):
        #check/change value for prop1
        print('using setter')
        self._prop1 = str(newval).upper()

In [62]: c = C()

In [63]: c['prop1']
Out[63]: 'Prop1 Calc Value'

In [64]: c['prop1'] = 'new value'
using setter

In [65]: c['prop1']
Out[65]: 'NEW VALUE'

In [66]: c.akey
Out[66]: 'avalue'

In [67]: c.att1
Out[67]: '1st attribute'
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you want your instances to be able to access descriptors via the subscript notation; I don't know why you're up to this but properties live in the class namespace so you'll need to look there.

Just try and get the descriptor from the class's dict and invoke it:

```
 def __getitem__(self,key):
    try:
        return self.__dict__[key]
    except KeyError:
        try: 
            return getattr(type(self), key).__get__(self)
        except KeyError:
            return self.data[key]
```

Then (I guess) you can do what you wanted:

```
>>> c = C()
>>> c['prop1']
'prop1'
```

Comment: like I said before, it's really just sugar for a module i'm building.

Comment: thanks that works for the getters. need to change the second `except` to `except AttributeError` though. I think i worked out the setters. Edited question w/ my final implementation